# Open Source or Freeware C Code Metrics tools?

Tags: c, complexity-theory, metrics, cohesion, code-size

I have been trying to find a tool (hopefully for MAC OS X but I don't mind migrating) -- that works -- for those dimensions but I had no luck. [Maultech](http://www.maultech.com/chrislott/resources/cmetrics/) mention some, and so does [this page](http://www.locmetrics.com/alternatives.html) but I was unable to make them work. Metre and ccount (listed on that page) seems to cover most of what I wanted. The tools also seem not up to date no anymore with makes me unsure if the outputs can still be trusted.

Is there any current C tool that can do this that is free or open source? Most of what I found is for Java or OO.

By simple metrics I mean for example calculating amount of, characters, blanks, functions, methods, amount of statements, depth of nests, etc.

By Size I mean line of code, and comments.

By Complexity I mean mccabe and halstead metric at the very least.

By Couple and Cohesion I mean interaction between function calls etc (this is a known SE principle).

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [Frama-c](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frama-C).

You may want to take a look at its [metrics plugin](http://frama-c.com/metrics.html) (**McCabe**'s cyclomatic complexity, **Halstead** complexity, Value analysis coverage estimate, etc)

> What is Frama-C ?
>
> Frama-C is an extensible and collaborative platform dedicated to source-code analysis of C software.